# Vokabel, Vokabular, Wortschatz

Tags: vocabulary, terminology

What is the difference between these three concepts? I think understand that der Wortschatz can refer to one's personal vocabulary (the set of words that one knows). What of das Vokabel / das Vokabular?

Comment: A *Vokabel* is an item from your *Wortschatz* (typically in a foreign language). *Wortschatz* is synonymous to "Vokabular*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*die Vokabel* = a single word of your vocabulary (*das Vokabular*), in particular a single word or phrase you learn when you study a foreign language. Hence *Vokabelheft* (vocabular book) where you write down these words or phrases.

*Vokabular* and *Wortschatz* are mostly synonyms, where *Vokabular* is either a more formal style level or used for the vocabulary of the certain specific field, e.g. *Fachvokabular* = (special) terminology, technical terms.

Another meaning of *Wortschatz* is thesaurus (book), e.g. *Der große Lernwortschatz Englisch*.

Answer (score 3):

The first meaning of *Wortschatz* (m.) is: the entirety of the words of a language, as in *der Wortschatz des Deutschen; der französische Wortschatz*

The second meaning of *Wortschatz* (m.) is: the entirety of the words someone **has at command** as in: *aktiver Wortschatz; passiver Wortschatz*

In both cases, *Wortschatz* cannot be replaced by *Vokabular*.

*Vokabular* (n.) is the entirety of the words someone **makes use of** as in: *Er ist 25 und hat das Vokabular eines achtjährigen Kind[e]s.* Here, *Wortschatz* can be used as a synonym: *Er ist 25 und hat den Wortschatz eines achtjährigen Kind[e]s.*

*Vokabular* (n.) can also mean 'the characteristic language of s.o.', as in: a) *technisches / juristisches Vokabular* or in: b) *'das Vokabular der Politiker:innen / der Pubertierenden, ...*.  a) neutrally denotes what is typical for the language of technicians / jurists, whereas b) often has a more or less pejorative connotation.

*Vokabel* (f.) is the word as such you are supposed to learn when you learn another language, as in: *Vokabeln lernen fällt mir schwer, aber es muss wohl sein.*

Note that *Wortschatz* and *Vokabular* are usually not used in the plural, whereas *(die) Vokabel**n*** probably occurs many times more often than *(die) Vokabel* (sing.)